# How to shorten/indent f-string line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've spent way too long working on this stupidly simple task. At this point I'm just bemused.

I have the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
# xyz defined elsewhere in code ... unimportant for this code style question

abc = f"Date and Time: {xyz.strftime('%A, %B %d at %I:%M:%S %p')}"
```

The last line (`abc = ...`) is over 80 characters long, so I'm trying to split it across two lines. I've tried the backslash (`\`), I've tried simply pressing "Enter" to put the code on a new line, and I've tried wrapping the code in parentheses. But each method returns a `SyntaxError`.

For example, if I type and execute:

```
abc = f"Date and Time: {xyz.strftime \
    ('%A, %B %d at %I:%M:%S %p')}"
```

I get the following error: `SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash`

How can I properly split this single line of code into two lines of code?

Comment: You don't need to mix f-strings and `strftime`. Either `xyz.strftime("Date and Time: %A, %B...")` or `f'{Date and Time: {xyz:%A, %B...}'` will suffice.

Comment: @chepner I did not know this! The first method works just fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would just extract the variable

```
t = xyz.strftime('%A, %B %d at %I:%M:%S %p')
abc = f"Date and Time: {t}"
```